# can't move right or left in iframe (from mobile)

Tags: html, css

I am building news aggregation website which embed news websites in responsive website, some these websites are not responsive. when i see it on mobile it looks like this (black is my website, red is news website aren't responsive) and i can't move right or left to see the rest of the page.. any suggestion ?

**Code**

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <iframe ..></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @sideroxylon it's simple code, but i have added it

Comment: Have you tried adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the iframe container?

Comment: @sideroxylon i tried it, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: add `overflow:auto` to the container div.